# ¿Obtener duración de una cita tomando horas de tablas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola quiero obtener el tiempo que se demoro la cita de los clientes, para esto quiero tomar el campo creation_date de una cita que se guarda en la tabla "transacciones" pero para determinar si la cita acabo utilizo el creation_date de otra tabla llamada transacciones_pagos, entonces lo que quiero es poder calcular cuanto tiempo estuvo un cliente, basicamente calcular las horas del creation_date de transacciones con el creation_date de transacciones_pagos, ambas tablas tienen una FK que es id_transaccion.

Hasta aqui lo que tengo, he podido seleccionar ambas fechas pero necesito otro campo que muestre el calculo en horas digamos que si el creation_date de transacciones fue a las 18:00:00 y el creation_date de transacciones_pagos fue 20:00:00 entonces otra deberia mostrarme que duro 02:00:00 dos horas, algo asi es mi idea, no se si se pueda por eso consulto

Comparto el query con el que muestro las creation_date:

```
SELECT trax.id_transaccion, 
       trax.creation_date AS ingreso, 
       trax_pago.creation_date AS salida 
FROM transacciones trax 
INNER JOIN transacciones_pagos trax_pago 
ON trax_pago.id_transaccion = trax.id_transaccion
```

Y un capture de lo que me muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguno pueda ayudarme con una solución gracias de antemano, para aclarar es una bd de mysql :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, T1.start_time, T2.end_time) as `diferencia_horas` 
   FROM tabla_1 T1 
   INNER JOIN tabla_2 T2 ON T2.id_tabla_2 = T1.tabla_2_id 
   WHERE T1.id_tabla_1 = valor
```

Espero que te ayude o te de una idea de como realizarlo

Comment: Si bien es una respuesta correcta, el editar y explicar que hiciste para resolver el problema no estaría de mas, considera leer [answer]

Comment: Gracias si me sirvio, tuve que hacer adaptaciones pero me sirvio como guia :)